# Error red in navigator when I try to download a file from a b64

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to force the download of a file (DOC, DOCX, ODT) using the B64 string and the content type but I obtain an 'ERROR RED in chrome', it strange because I´ve downloaded images or PDFs and these work perfectly

HTML

```
    <div class="botones width-100 flex">
        <button class="basico blanco">
            <a [href]="sanitize(doc)" target="_self" download=""> 
                <i class="nio-icon-download texto-negro font-md"></i>
            </a>
        </button>
    </div>
</td>
```

JS (I´m working with Angular)

```
sanitize(data: DocumentosListView) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`data:${data.contentType};base64,${data.documentoName}`);
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details about what this "ERROR RED in chrome" is about.

Comment: I fixed that error using a blob, I was searching and found that chrome block the downloads when they have a big size